# xcode 4.5.1 not loading .gdbinit

Tags: xcode, gdb

I have a .gdbinit file.  I have been using it for years.  It is in my home directory.  I still need to do Xcode debugging under gdb, not lldb.  But Xcode 4.5.1 does not load the file when it runs an app.

I can load it manually with 'source ~/.gdbinit'.  But that's a pain!  Any way to configure it to load on launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding `source ~/.gdbinit` to the Pre-actions part of the "Run" scheme in your project (Cmd + < to access the scheme editor)?

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere and have experienced that Xcode 4.5 and 4.5.1 have many bugs in them  and this could be one of them. I cannot really help with this but to say:

1.) remove xcode.app from finder in applications

2.) download Xcode 4.4.1 from the apple website: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%204.4.1

3.) put it into the applications folder.

4.) Run Xcode 4.4.1 and run your app!

I have had to do this twice due to these two versions of xcode being buggy.